# filters on Mapbox gl on existing example

Tags: javascript, geojson, mapbox-gl-js

Im trying to make a map with markers and filters from external geojson source, and the closest example i found is in this website http://bl.ocks.org/ryanbaumann/04c442906638e27db9da243f29195592 
i removed the second source and im hoping to create more filters in checkboxes and dropdowns ONLY. My problem is the following:
when i choose from the dropdown filter it also shows the other markers but in smaller unclickable points. how can i make it show only the ones that are relevant for example when i choose " Pedestrian Fatalities" it will show only the ones that have a value there and not the others. Im not necesseraly looking for a code-based solution although it would be helpfull.

```js
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoicnNiYXVtYW5uIiwiYSI6IjdiOWEzZGIyMGNkOGY3NWQ4ZTBhN2Y5ZGU2Mzg2NDY2In0.jycgv7qwF8MMIWt4cT0RaQ';
var bounds = [
  [-75.04728500751165, 39.68392799015035],
  [-72.91058699000139, 41.87764500765852]
];
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map',
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
  center: [-74.0059, 40.7128],
  zoom: 10,
  minZoom: 9,
  maxZoom: 18,
  pitch: 0,
  maxBounds: bounds
});

function init() {
  map.addSource('veh-incidents-1', {
    type: 'geojson',
    data: 'https://dl.dropbox.com/s/z4hajzr32e59kv4/nyc_pedcyc_collisions_1.geojson?dl=0',
    buffer: 0,
    maxzoom: 12
  });



  if (window.location.search.indexOf('embed') !== -1) map.scrollZoom.disable();

  map.addLayer({
    'id': 'veh-incd-1',
    'type': 'circle',
    'source': 'veh-incidents-1',
    'paint': {
      'circle-color': {
        property: 'CYC_INJ',
        type: 'interval',
        stops: [
          [1, 'orange'],
          [2, 'red']
        ]
      },
      'circle-radius': {
        property: 'CYC_INJ',
        base: 3,
        type: 'interval',
        stops: [
          [1, 3],
          [2, 8],
          [3, 12]
        ]
      },
      'circle-opacity': 0.8,
      'circle-blur': 0.5
    },
    'filter': ['>=', 'CYC_INJ', 1]
  }, 'waterway-label');



  map.addLayer({
    'id': 'veh-incd-base-1',
    'type': 'circle',
    'source': 'veh-incidents-1',
    'paint': {
      'circle-color': 'yellow',
      'circle-radius': 3,
      'circle-opacity': 0.3,
      'circle-blur': 1
    },
    'filter': ['<', 'CYC_INJ', 1]
  }, 'waterway-label');


};

map.once('style.load', function(e) {
  init();
  map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl());
  map.on('click', function(e) {
    var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, {
      layers: ['veh-incd-1']
    });
    if (!features.length) {
      return;
    }
    var feature = features[0];

    var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup()
      .setLngLat(map.unproject(e.point))
      .setHTML('<h3>Collision Detail</h3>' +
        '<ul>' +
        '<li>Year: <b>' + feature.properties.YEAR + '</b></li>' +
        '<li>Pedestrian Injuries: <b>' + feature.properties.PED_INJ + '</b></li>' +
        '<li>Pedestrian Fatalities: <b>' + feature.properties.PED_KIL + '</b></li>' +
        '<li>Cyclist Injuries: <b>' + feature.properties.CYC_INJ + '</b></li>' +
        '<li>Cyclist Fatalities: <b>' + feature.properties.CYC_KIL + '</b></li>' +
        '</ul>')
      .addTo(map);
  });

  //Hide loading bar once tiles from geojson are loaded
  map.on('data', function(e) {
    if (e.dataType === 'source' && e.sourceId === 'veh-incidents-1') {
      document.getElementById("loader").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
  })

  // Use the same approach as above to indicate that the symbols are clickable
  // by changing the cursor style to 'pointer'.
  map.on('mousemove', function(e) {
    var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, {
      layers: ['veh-incd-1']
    });
    map.getCanvas().style.cursor = (features.length) ? 'pointer' : '';
  });
  var prop = document.getElementById('prop');
  prop.addEventListener('change', function() {
    map.setPaintProperty('veh-incd-1', 'circle-color', {
      property: prop.value,
      type: 'interval',
      stops: [
        [1, 'green'],
        [2, 'red']
      ]
    });

    map.setPaintProperty('veh-incd-1', 'circle-radius', {
      property: prop.value,
      base: 3,
      type: 'interval',
      stops: [
        [1, 3],
        [2, 6],
        [3, 9]
      ]
    });

    map.setFilter('veh-incd-1', ['>=', prop.value, 1])

  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8' />
  <title></title>
  <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
  <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.41.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
  <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.41.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
  <link href='https://www.mapbox.com/base/latest/base.css' rel='stylesheet' />
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    #map {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .map-overlay {
      position: absolute;
      width: 180px;
      top: 0;
      left: 10px;
      padding: 10px;
      margin-left: 5px;
      margin-top: 2px;
      margin-bottom: 2px;
      margin-right: 5px;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .map-overlay .map-overlay-inner {
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
      color: #fff;
      box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10);
      border-radius: 3px;
      padding: 10px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .map-overlay-inner fieldset {
      border: none;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0 0 10px;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    /* Dark attribution */
    
    .mapboxgl-ctrl.mapboxgl-ctrl-attrib {
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    }
    
    .mapboxgl-ctrl.mapboxgl-ctrl-attrib a {
      color: #fff;
    }
    /* Dark popup */
    
    .mapboxgl-popup-content {
      background-color: #202020;
      color: #fff;
      margin-left: 5px;
      margin-top: 2px;
      margin-bottom: 2px;
      margin-right: 5px;
      z-index: 1000;
    }
    
    .mapboxgl-popup-anchor-bottom-left .mapboxgl-popup-tip,
    .mapboxgl-popup-anchor-bottom-right .mapboxgl-popup-tip,
    .mapboxgl-popup-anchor-bottom .mapboxgl-popup-tip {
      border-top-color: #202020;
    }
    
    .mapboxgl-popup-anchor-top-left .mapboxgl-popup-tip,
    .mapboxgl-popup-anchor-top-right .mapboxgl-popup-tip,
    .mapboxgl-popup-anchor-top .mapboxgl-popup-tip {
      border-bottom-color: #202020;
    }
    
    .mapboxgl-popup-anchor-right .mapboxgl-popup-tip {
      border-left-color: #202020;
    }
    
    .mapboxgl-popup-anchor-left .mapboxgl-popup-tip {
      border-right-color: #202020;
    }
    
    #popup-menu ul,
    #menu li {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      z-index: 100;
    }
    
    .mapboxgl-ctrl-group {
      -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
    }
    
    .loader {
      margin: -10px 0 0 -250px;
      height: 100px;
      width: 20%;
      position: fixed;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 1em;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      margin: 0 auto 1em;
      z-index: 9999;
    }
    /*
  Set the color of the icon
*/
    
    svg path,
    svg rect {
      fill: #FF6700;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='map'></div>
  <div class='map-overlay top'>
    <div class='map-overlay-inner'>
      <fieldset>
        <label><b>Select property</b></label>
        <select id='prop' name='prop'>
          <option value='CYC_INJ'>Cyclist Injuries</option>
          <option value='CYC_KIL'>Cyclist Fatalities</option>
          <option value='PED_INJ'>Pedestrian Injuries</option>
          <option value='PED_KIL'>Pedestrian Fatalities</option>
        </select>
      </fieldset>
      <b><a href="https://kiosker.gr" target="_blank">Kiosker</a></b>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="loader loader--style1" title="0" id="loader">
    <svg version="1.1" id="loader-1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="40px" height="40px" viewBox="0 0 40 40" enable-background="new 0 0 40 40" xml:space="preserve">
            <path opacity="0.2" fill="#000" d="M20.201,5.169c-8.254,0-14.946,6.692-14.946,14.946c0,8.255,6.692,14.946,14.946,14.946
    s14.946-6.691,14.946-14.946C35.146,11.861,28.455,5.169,20.201,5.169z M20.201,31.749c-6.425,0-11.634-5.208-11.634-11.634
    c0-6.425,5.209-11.634,11.634-11.634c6.425,0,11.633,5.209,11.633,11.634C31.834,26.541,26.626,31.749,20.201,31.749z" />
            <path fill="#000" d="M26.013,10.047l1.654-2.866c-2.198-1.272-4.743-2.012-7.466-2.012h0v3.312h0
    C22.32,8.481,24.301,9.057,26.013,10.047z">
                <animateTransform attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0 20 20" to="360 20 20" dur="0.5s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
            </path>
        </svg>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in pointing the mouse pointer over a circle with a small radius, so use the [`queryRenderedFeatures`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#queryrenderedfeature) function not with a point geometry, but with region geometry as an argument:

```
// https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#queryrenderedfeatures
map.on('mousemove', function(e) {
  var boxSize = new mapboxgl.Point(10, 10);
  var sw = e.point.clone().add(boxSize);
  var ne = e.point.clone().sub(boxSize);
  var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures([sw, ne], {
    layers: ['veh-incd-1']
  });
  map.getCanvas().style.cursor = (features.length) ? 'pointer' : '';
});
```

[ https://jsfiddle.net/5u8xgh61/ ]

Comment: Sorry for the delay and thank you for your input! i deleted the

`map.addLayer({
    'id': 'veh-incd-base-1',
    'type': 'circle',
    'source': 'veh-incidents-1',
    'paint': {
      'circle-color': 'yellow',
      'circle-radius': 3,
      'circle-opacity': 0.3,
      'circle-blur': 1
    },
    'filter': ['<', 'CYC_INJ', 1]
  }, 'waterway-label');
` and everything seems fine!